# limit of square root of x whether one or does not exist

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x}$$

I am not sure whether this limit approches to 1 or does not exist. According to Thomas Finny it does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

The function $\sqrt{x}$ is continous on $[0,\infty)$, so it is simply $$\lim_{x\to0+}\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{0}=0.$$

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{x \to 0+} \sqrt{x} = 0$. Never it will  be 1

Answer (score 2):

For a limit to exist it must be a real number$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sqrt{x} = 0$$ $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} = \text{DNE}$$

because $\sqrt{x} $ is not real for $x<0$

Since the left limit is not equal to the right limit , the total limit Does Not Exist.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} x$ does not exist, because $\lim_{x\to 0+} x=0$ but $x\neq 0$ for $x<0$.

Comment: I don't see how that disqualifies my argument. For x < 0 $ \sqrt{x} $ is not real.

Comment: $x$ is not $0$ for $x<0$, but it's left limit can be (and is) $0$. Likewise $\sqrt{x}$ is not real for $x<0$, but it's left limit can be (and is) $0$.

Comment: You have either to discuss the complex root-function (then the left limit exists and is zero), or discuss the real function (then the function's domain is $[0,\infty)$ and the left limit requirement does not apply, because $0$ is not an inner point).

Comment: I discuss the real function. Since it is undefined for x < 0 the limit from the left of 0 cannot exist. IMHO , i don't need 0 to be an inner point.

Comment: My interpretation of the OP is that Thomas Finny is asking for the 2-sided limit , how can there be a 2-sided limit when you don't have 2 sides? :)

Comment: @neofoxmulder, you are correct.. Anyways, this question is stupid.

Comment: @neofoxmulder The symbol-word-sequence: “$\lim_{x\to0^-}$ does not exist.” is not a statement, i.e., can't be neither true nor false, since $\sqrt{x}$ isn't defined for $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sqrt{x}$ (as a real-valued function) is not defined for $x<0$, so we can only talk about the limit coming from the right:

$$\lim_{x \to 0+} \sqrt{x}$$

Which exists and is zero.